# Is Headless JS useful in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

I was Android/iOS Developer. And I am studying React Native now.
I wonder that is Headless js useful in React Native development environment.

I can make Android/iOS native module/UI component with RCTBridge.
And also I used a background task library like WorkManager(Android) etc..

For example, WorkManager is robust library for background task in Android also in Jetpack Project.

Also, there is no support for iOS with headless js right?
So, is the best way to implement background task in React native(Android) is headless js?